# What are the differences between DIACAP and RMF?

Tags: pci-scope

I am currently certifying systems (products) under DIACAP (DoD Information Assurance Certification and Accreditation Process). In the future we will need to use RMF (Risk Management Framework).

- What are the key differences between these two processes?
- What are the similarities (for instance they both use a POA&M)
- Is there a defined, documented transition from the older process to the newer? (Something with more meat than the slides at http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/SMA/ispab/documents/minutes/2012-10/ispab_oct2012_dcussatt_dod-rmf-transition-brief.pdf)
- Has the reciprocity aspect of RMF worked in practice, between different branches of the DoD and or services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Concept of Operations (CONOPS)
- Ports, Protocols, & Services Management (PPSM)

  - Hardware / Software list
  - Network diagram
- System Security Plan (SSP) / Application Security Plan (formerly DIP/SIP)
- Security Assessment Report (SAR) aka. Risk Assessment Report (RAR)
- Information Security Continuous Monitoring (ISCM) Plan
- Plan of Action and Milestones (POA&M)
- Configuration Management Plan (CMP)
- Configuration Control Board Charter (CCB)
- Incident Response Plan (IRP)
- Rules of Behavior (ROB) / Acceptable Use Policy (AUP)
- Systems Administration Manual (SAM)
- Continuity of Operations Plan (COOP) or Business Continuity Plan (BCP)
- Disaster Recovery Plan (DRP)
- Contingency Plan (CP)
- System Level Agreements (SLA), Memorandum of Agreements (MOA) or Memorandum of Understanding (MOU)

DIACAP to RMF artifact differences:

- SSP replaces System Identification Profile (SIP) and DIACAP Implementation Plan (DIP)
- SAR replaces Scorecard, Evaluation Risk Report (ERR)
- Security Control Assessor (SCA) replaces Validator or ACA
- Security Authorization Package (SAP) replaces DIACAP Package
- Information System Security Officer (ISSO) / Manager (ISSM) a replaces IAM / IAO